# Error in Start/Stop Window Service from ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-services, authorization

I created a windows service in C# and it is executing fine. And i have a ASP.NET application  from that i'm trying to access (start/stop) it. It was working fine in my local machine and when i deploy it in my server it was not working. when i click the button to start stop the service  gives an error:

> Access is denied error message'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run application pool that hosts/runs your ASP.NET application under user who has enough permissions.

Note that it's a potential security hole!

Instead I'd add a layer like web service available only locally to delegate such task.